# Making my first tatoo, kinda nervous.. Please check my calculations! :)

Tags: linux, unix

So my basic idéa was to make a list of important dates in my life (starting with my birth) in unix timestamps(since this is where i started out as a programmer)...

Only thing is, i left php a while ago and when looking at this number.. im just thinking im going to mess something up or miss something crucial! :D

So please correct me!

556246980

Is August 18th, 1987 01:03:00 AM RIGHT?

Also..

Should I consider timezones in my tattoo? Thoughts? I am CET!

Comment: My thoughts is that a tattoo is something you'll later regret in life, and is never a good idea. But that's not what you're asking, is it?

Comment: I WOULD STRONGLY RECONSIDER THIS ... Getting a tattoo with a numerical value in it would offend a lot of people on anyone younger than 80 ... Know your historical and cultural surroundings.

Comment: I think a tatoo should state something personal, I live in Sweden and unless I missed something really crucial I don't think people take offense by numbers.. And as for people born before 1970 I would recommend using a - to joke things up :)

Comment: People born 80 years ago would've been born in the 1930s. Know anybody in the 1930s or 1940s that got tattoos of numbers on their bodies against their will? That's all I'm saying. It could be easily done to be sharp, I'm just cautioning you, as a friend on this great brotherhood of a site. Just promise me you'll discuss it with your tattoo artists first ;-)

Comment: I'm going to put it on my back, as far as I know, the tatooes you are reffering to were located on the lower arm. But I get your point and I and understand what you are saying!

Comment: I bet it would look sharp as part of a tickertape too, or on the readout of a calculator :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Linux you can get the time of a Unix timestamp like that: `date -d @556246980`. So yes, it is `Tue Aug 18 01:03:00 UTC 1987`.

Unix timestamps are measured from the epoch, Thu Jan  1 00:00:00 UTC 1970. They do not support time zones. Unix considers time zones as a presentation artifact.

For the other dates, you can also ask `date` to give you the corresponding time stamp: `date -d 'Aug 18 01:03:00 UTC 1987' +%s`.